# styled-components are breaking the union prop type causing unsafe typescript behaviour

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

Suppose I have a simple union Props type and a simple function Component:

```
type Props = { a: string; b?: never } | { b: number; a?: never };

const Component: React.FC<Props> = props => {
  return <>{props.a ?? props.b}</>;
};
```

If one tries to instantiate the Component as follows, naturally you would get a typescript error since both `a` and `b` cannot be passed as props simultaneously

```
const App1 = () => {
  return <Component a="a" b={1} />; // typescript error
};
```

However, if I use styled components we no longer get a typescript error. See example

```
const SComponent = styled(Component)``;

const App2 = () => {
  return <SComponent a="a" b={1} />; // no typescript error
};
```

The only way I found to overcome this, is setting the prop type explicitly like so

```
const SComponentWithPropType = styled(Component)<Props>``;
```

but I would like to avoid doing that for all my styled instances.

Is there any other workaround? and why do we have this discrepancy in the first place?

Running typescript: 4.9.5 and styled-components: 5.1.1.

Your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Not able to reproduce the error. Check [this](https://tsplay.dev/wRAAQW).